# Azure Application to authenticate users

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, pulumi

I’m trying to create an .NET console application to authenticate users for an  Azure function app. I want to authenticate users using their AD credentials and then create a token based on that. I believe I need to enable “Public client flows” in order to achieve this. I’m pretty new to this, but after many failed attempts I managed to get it working after setting the Application ID URI and the scope in the “Expose an API” section. I believe the manifest refers to this property as “identifierUris”. An according to some findings both public access and identifierUris cannot be used at the same time.
Is there an alternative way to achieve this? Any explanations or reasonings as to why this is not ideal would be appreciated as well.

This is the code we're using to retrieve the token and use it:

```csharp
var publicClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                       .Create(clientId)
                       .WithAuthority(authorityUri)
                       .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                       .Build();

var accessTokenRequest = publicClient.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes);
var accessToken = await accessTokenRequest.ExecuteAsync();
restRequest.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

This is the Pulumi code creating the Azure AD Application, where `functionApp` is the `Pulumi.Azure.AppService.FunctionApp` that we are trying to authorize against:

```csharp
var azureApp = new AzureAD.Application(name, new AzureAD.ApplicationArgs
{
    DisplayName = name,
    AvailableToOtherTenants = false,
    Homepage = "https://VisualStudio/SPN",
    Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow = true,
    ReplyUrls = { "http://localhost" },
    IdentifierUris =
    {
       functionApp.DefaultHostname.Apply(dnsName => "https://" + dnsName)
    },
    PublicClient = true
}, new CustomResourceOptions {DependsOn = functionApp});
```

When `PublicClient` is set to false, this deploys fine. When it is set to `true`, the the underlying API call returns a 400 error with this text:

```
Property identifierUris is invalid
```

So we set `PublicClient` to false and then manually update it to true in the portal, which works fine:

[image: Azure Portal App Registration Authentication tab]

What are we missing?

Comment: Which authentication flow are you using?

Comment: Why can't  use `Public client flows` and `identifierUris` at the same time? Are there any special instructions in official documents?

Comment: @CarlZhao Please take a look at the edits I've made to elaborate on the issue. I'm working with Mifla.

Comment: @CarlZhao I don't recall any official document mentioning anything of the like, but please take a look at the following link, https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7955#issuecomment-500265900 . Please also note that we are not using a web platform.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `PublicClient` to `true` because it applies to ROPC flow, Device Code Flow or Windows Integrated Auth flow as your screenshot shows.

But according to your code, I think you are not using any the three auth flows.

You should create a new app registration which represents the API/server side (your Azure function app) and do "Expose an API".

Add the scope/permission (exposed by the API/server side) in your app registration which represents the client side (.NET console application).

To use `PublicClientApplicationBuilder`, you just need to modify `"allowPublicClient": true` in the manifest file of the app registration of the client side. Don't add any `IdentifierUris` or set the Application ID URI and the scope in the "Expose an API" section because this should be done in the app registration which represents the API/server side.